# NSPredicate ANY with multiple columns

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I've 2 tables Person and Social.

Person has multiple Socials.
Socials has username and Service.

I'm trying to write a predicate on Person table which will match the people with proper username and service from the Social table. The statement below is wrong. Please let me know if there is a proper syntax to achive the same or if there is any better method to achieve the same.

```
    [predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" ANY (socials.username = %@ 
                                 AND socials.service = %@)",@"username",@"service"]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a typical use-case for a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(socials, $s, $s.username = %@ AND $s.service = %@).@count > 0",
    @"username", @"service"]
```